# Spring Security PreAuthentication checkForPrincipalChanges bug?

Tags: spring-security

Is this a bug in Spring Security?

org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter
line:134

```
...
Object principal = getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(request);
    if (checkForPrincipalChanges &&
        !currentUser.getName().equals(principal)) {
        logger.debug("Pre-authenticated principal has changed to " + principal + " and will be reauthenticated");
...
```

Shouldn't it consider a null preAuthenticatedPrincipal to be a non change?

I shouldn't have to send the preAuthenticatedPrincipal with every request should I?

Shouldn't there be a check to see if this value is null?

Shouldn't this be

```
Object principal = getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(request);
    if (checkForPrincipalChanges && 
        principal!=null &&
        !currentUser.getName().equals(principal)) {
        logger.debug("Pre-authenticated principal has changed to " + principal + " and will be reauthenticated");
```

Notice addition of **principal!=null &&**

This was found in spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar

If this is indeed a bug then I think I am working around it by adding the following override to my implementation:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal((HttpServletRequest) request) != null) {
        super.doFilter(request, response, chain);
    } else {
        //if the request did not include a preauthenticated principal then we should just continue are merry way down the filter chain
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Let me know if I am wrong about this being a bug and whether I missed anything in my workaround.

Answer (score 2):

This is not a bug for the following reasons.

- `doAuthenticate()` method returns without an error if *preauthenticated principal* is `null`.
- In `requiresAuthentication(`) method, you can turn on or off `checkForPrincipalChanges`
- The following check happens only if `currentUser` is **not** `null`.

  if (checkForPrincipalChanges && !currentUser.getName().equals(principal)) {

This check should happen as it is, since there is indeed a change in principal - from a **non-null** `currentUser` to a **null** `principal` now.

Comment: How do I enable checkForPrincipalChanges without having to have the client send the Pre-authenticated principal in every request?